# Can't install software from Software Center

Tags: apt

I cant install anything from software centre, I get this error every time I click on install,  "Require installation packages"

Here is my output of **sudo apt get update**

```
[sudo] password for gaurav: 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security Release.gpg                   
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/main Translation-en   
Get:1 http://deb.opera.com stable Release.gpg [189B]                           
Ign http://deb.opera.com/opera/ stable/non-free Translation-en                 
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/multiverse Translation-en_IN
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/restricted Translation-en_IN
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/universe Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/universe Translation-en_IN
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security Release                       
Ign http://deb.opera.com/opera/ stable/non-free Translation-en_IN              
Hit http://deb.opera.com stable Release                                        
Get:2 http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg [189B]                           
Ign http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/ stable/main Translation-en      
Ign http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/ stable/main Translation-en_IN   
Hit http://download.virtualbox.org maverick Release.gpg                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/main Sources                  
Ign http://deb.opera.com stable/non-free i386 Packages                         
Get:3 http://dl.google.com stable Release [1,338B]                             
Get:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release.gpg [307B]                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/bean123ch/burg/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/bean123ch/burg/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/ maverick/non-free Translation-en
Ign http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/ maverick/non-free Translation-en_IN
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/restricted Sources            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/universe Sources              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/multiverse Sources            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/main i386 Packages            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/restricted i386 Packages      
Ign http://deb.opera.com stable/non-free i386 Packages                         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/universe i386 Packages        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/multiverse i386 Packages      
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick Release.gpg                              
  Could not connect to extras.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.33). - connect (110: Connection timed out)
Err http://archive.canonical.com maverick Release.gpg                          
  Could not connect to archive.canonical.com:80 (91.189.88.33). - connect (110: Connection timed out)
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en              
  Unable to connect to extras.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en_IN           
  Unable to connect to extras.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ maverick/partner Translation-en       
  Unable to connect to archive.canonical.com:http:
Err http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ maverick/partner Translation-en_IN    
  Unable to connect to archive.canonical.com:http:
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick Release                                  
Ign http://archive.canonical.com maverick Release                              
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick/main Sources/DiffIndex                   
Ign http://archive.canonical.com maverick/partner Sources/DiffIndex            
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex             
Ign http://archive.canonical.com maverick/partner i386 Packages/DiffIndex      
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick/main Sources                             
Ign http://archive.canonical.com maverick/partner Sources                      
Ign http://archive.canonical.com maverick/partner i386 Packages                
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick/main i386 Packages                       
Ign http://archive.canonical.com maverick/partner Sources                      
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick/main Sources                             
Ign http://archive.canonical.com maverick/partner i386 Packages                
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick/main i386 Packages                       
Err http://archive.canonical.com maverick/partner Sources                      
  Unable to connect to archive.canonical.com:http:
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick/main Sources                             
  Unable to connect to extras.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://archive.canonical.com maverick/partner i386 Packages                
  Unable to connect to archive.canonical.com:http:
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick/main i386 Packages                       
  Unable to connect to extras.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick Release.gpg                          
  Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (111.91.91.37). - connect (110: Connection timed out)
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en          
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en_IN       
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/multiverse Translation-en    
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/multiverse Translation-en_IN 
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/restricted Translation-en    
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/restricted Translation-en_IN 
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/universe Translation-en      
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/universe Translation-en_IN   
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates Release.gpg                  
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/main Translation-en  
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/main Translation-en_IN
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/multiverse Translation-en
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/multiverse Translation-en_IN
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/restricted Translation-en
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/restricted Translation-en_IN
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/universe Translation-en
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/universe Translation-en_IN
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick Release                              
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates Release                      
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main Sources/DiffIndex               
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted Sources/DiffIndex         
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe Sources/DiffIndex           
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex         
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex         
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex   
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex     
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex   
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/main Sources/DiffIndex       
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/restricted Sources/DiffIndex 
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/universe Sources/DiffIndex   
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex 
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex 
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main Sources                         
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted Sources                   
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe Sources                     
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/multiverse Sources                   
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main i386 Packages                   
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted i386 Packages             
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe i386 Packages               
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/multiverse i386 Packages             
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/main Sources                 
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/restricted Sources           
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/universe Sources             
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/multiverse Sources           
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/main i386 Packages           
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/restricted i386 Packages     
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/universe i386 Packages       
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/multiverse i386 Packages     
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main Sources                         
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted Sources                   
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe Sources                     
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/multiverse Sources                   
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main i386 Packages                   
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted i386 Packages             
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe i386 Packages               
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/multiverse i386 Packages             
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/main Sources                 
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/restricted Sources           
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/universe Sources             
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/multiverse Sources           
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/main i386 Packages           
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/restricted i386 Packages     
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/universe i386 Packages       
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/multiverse i386 Packages     
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main Sources                         
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted Sources                   
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe Sources                     
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/multiverse Sources                   
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main i386 Packages                   
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted i386 Packages             
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe i386 Packages               
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/multiverse i386 Packages             
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/main Sources                 
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/restricted Sources           
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/universe Sources             
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/multiverse Sources           
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/main i386 Packages           
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/restricted i386 Packages     
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/universe i386 Packages       
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/multiverse i386 Packages     
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Hit http://deb.opera.com stable/non-free i386 Packages                         
Hit http://download.virtualbox.org maverick Release                            
Get:5 http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages [613B]          
Get:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release.gpg [316B]             
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/am-monkeyd/nautilus-elementary-ppa/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/am-monkeyd/nautilus-elementary-ppa/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en_IN
Get:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release.gpg [316B]                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/cairo-dock-team/ppa/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/cairo-dock-team/ppa/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en_IN
Get:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release.gpg [316B]                     
Hit http://download.virtualbox.org maverick/non-free i386 Packages             
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/chromium-daily/stable/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/chromium-daily/stable/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en_IN
Get:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release.gpg [307B]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/crebs/ppa/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/crebs/ppa/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en_IN
Get:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release.gpg [316B]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/docky-core/ppa/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/docky-core/ppa/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en_IN
Get:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release.gpg [316B]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/flozz/flozz/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/flozz/flozz/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en_IN
Get:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release.gpg [316B]                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/loneowais/ppa/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/loneowais/ppa/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en_IN
Get:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release.gpg [316B]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/shutter/ppa/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/shutter/ppa/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en_IN
Get:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release.gpg [316B]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/tiheum/equinox/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/tiheum/equinox/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en_IN
Get:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release.gpg [316B]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en_IN
Get:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release.gpg [316B]                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en_IN
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release  
Get:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release [57.3kB]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main Sources                             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main i386 Packages                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main Sources                             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main i386 Packages                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main Sources                             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main i386 Packages                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main Sources                             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main i386 Packages
Get:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main Sources [352B]
Get:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main i386 Packages [779B]             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main Sources                             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main i386 Packages                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main i386 Packages                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main Sources                             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main i386 Packages
Fetched 64.5kB in 5min 51s (184B/s)
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY FC6D7D9D009ED615
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/Release.gpg  Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (111.91.91.37). - connect (110: Connection timed out)

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/i18n/Translation-en.bz2  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/i18n/Translation-en_IN.bz2  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en.bz2  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_IN.bz2  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/restricted/i18n/Translation-en.bz2  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_IN.bz2  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/universe/i18n/Translation-en.bz2  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/universe/i18n/Translation-en_IN.bz2  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en.bz2  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en_IN.bz2  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en.bz2  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_IN.bz2  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/restricted/i18n/Translation-en.bz2  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_IN.bz2  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-en.bz2  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-en_IN.bz2  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/Release.gpg  Could not connect to archive.canonical.com:80 (91.189.88.33). - connect (110: Connection timed out)

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/partner/i18n/Translation-en.bz2  Unable to connect to archive.canonical.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/partner/i18n/Translation-en_IN.bz2  Unable to connect to archive.canonical.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/Release.gpg  Could not connect to extras.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.33). - connect (110: Connection timed out)

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/i18n/Translation-en.bz2  Unable to connect to extras.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/i18n/Translation-en_IN.bz2  Unable to connect to extras.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/partner/source/Sources.gz  Unable to connect to archive.canonical.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/source/Sources.gz  Unable to connect to extras.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/partner/binary-i386/Packages.gz  Unable to connect to archive.canonical.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  Unable to connect to extras.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/source/Sources.gz  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/restricted/source/Sources.gz  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/universe/source/Sources.gz  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/multiverse/source/Sources.gz  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/restricted/binary-i386/Packages.gz  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/universe/binary-i386/Packages.gz  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages.gz  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/main/source/Sources.gz  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/restricted/source/Sources.gz  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/universe/source/Sources.gz  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/multiverse/source/Sources.gz  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages.gz  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages.gz  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages.gz  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
gaurav@gaurav-HCL-ME-Laptop:~$
```

Comment: Hmm , did you try removing Shutter ppa ? If it still doesnt work , how about changing the server where all updates and ppa received from ? Currently , which update server are you using ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I went back thinking what was the last apt I did and found out it was shutter ppa I added, after that I started getting errors on apt-get. 
I deleted the ppa and now everything is fine.

Any idea? what would have caused the shutter ppa to break the software installation.

Comment: +1 self answers are good for AU. I think that the shutter ppa is a red-herring; from the very first error listed it couldn't reach http://extras.ubuntu.com which leads me to believe you had a temporary network interruption which just happened to go away while you were trying to figure it out.

Comment: For future reference, you can edit your question to add this information in, rather than create an "answer" :)

Answer (score -3):

to add shutter ppa folow this guide :

Ubuntu

1. You can add a PPA to your system with a single line in your terminal. Open a terminal and enter:

> sudo add-apt-repository
>   ppa:shutter/ppa

1. Now, as a one-off, you should tell your system to pull down the latest list of software from each archive it knows about, including the PPA you just added:

> sudo apt-get update

1. Install Shutter

> sudo apt-get install shutter

Comment: What if these are the sources for the packages he is trying to install ?

Comment: in the future you might want to delete your old answer and start a new one when you radically change it. The people who previously downvoted you may not still want to downvote you now.

Comment: When I tried to add the sudo ppa repository it came back with an error message cannot add PPA: 'ppa shutter/ubuntu/ppa' then another error saying 'shutter' user or team does not exist. Please help I can't do anything online, updating or downloading on this computer since upgrading to bionic beaver and since downloading wine hq.